# Joomla parameter for template module

Tags: php, joomla

I have a template "ja_purity_ii_something" could be from [joomlart.com](http://www.joomlart.com/). Anyway, this template contains modules like `/html/mod_latestnews/default.php`.

In this file a parameter `$list` magically turns up.

How can I change this parameter?

Some code from `default.php`:

```
<?php if (count($list)) : ?>
<div id="latestnews_outer_container">
        <div class="latestnews_image_container" style="background-image:url(images/Startseite/startseite_1.jpg)">
                <?php $li = 0; ?>
                <?php foreach ($list as $item) : ?>
                <?php $itemparams=new JParameter($item->itemattribs); ?>
                        <img src="images/Startseite/<?php echo $itemparams->get('keyref'); ?>" class="latestnews_image" id="latestnews_<?php echo $li;?>_image" />
                <?php $li++; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: `$list` is most likely coming from `root/modules/mod_latestnews/mod_latestnews.php`. Be careful when editing this file if you do as if you update your site, it will override any changes as this file can not be made a template override unlike the *default.php*

Comment: There is no `mod_latestnews` could it be coming from `mod_articles_latest` or `mod_articles_news`? How could I change it? Is there some config page I am missing?

Comment: If there is no `mod_latestnews` in the modules folder then the folder in the `html` folder is overriding nothing. In `/html/mod_latestnews/default.php`, try adding something like `echo "test";` somewhere to see if this displays on the page. Let me know

Comment: Strange. There is an `echo "asdf";` but it does not display but the html code below is showing up after I changed `layouts/blocks/topsl.php`. It has to be connected to right_top, somehow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to edit articles. If you open an article, select "basic options" on the right and the last field is "key reference". Not sure how this is all connected but if I insert a jpg name it works.